# PHP preg_split is not returning a proper value

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to split a wordpress Blogpost title after the character is found so it doesnt cut off like an explode would do, but it gives me the following var_dump:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }
```

here is my code:

```
$title = $post['post_title'];
$titlepart = preg_split("/(.+)([.,?!]{1})(.+)/", $title);
var_dump($titlepart);
```

any Ideas?

Comment: `.` matches any character in regular expressions, you need to escape the characters if you wish to match them literally.

Comment: yes, got it working... I shouldn't have put in the (.+) because the preg_split does that, but the ? in the middle of my text is cut of where it splits

Comment: What characters are you trying to match?  `?` doesn't mean a question mark, `\?` does...

Comment: and capturing groups are pointless here :)

Comment: I have the text "Koningsdag 2017: Waar komt het vandaan?
En wat u moet weten over deze dag" and I want the second part to show on a different line, but my preg_split gives back  array(3) { [0]=> string(38) "Koningsdag 2017: Waar komt het vandaan" [1]=> string(34) " En wat u moet weten over deze dag" [2]=> string(0) "" }

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding of what you're trying to do is split the `title` by a control character of some kind, in the example you've chosen four: `,`, `.`, `!` and `?`.  You expect the title to be split into two (so the control characters to definitely appear, and hopefully only appear once - although we can protect against multiples we have to make an assumption - I put them all in the second line).

Here are two solutions - using `preg_match` and using `strpbrk`.  I've included some example strings at the top (`$ts`) and the expected solutions in the comment immediately below.

```
<?php

$ts=[
    'Koningsdag 2017: Waar komt het vandaan? En wat u moet weten over deze dag',
    'King\'s Day 2017: You love it! You won\'t believe how old it is',
    'Queen of hearts: Foul-tempered. Find out what Alice did',
    'Wise owl: What goes up, must come down',
    'Shakespeare: Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them',
    //'No delimiter',
    //''
];
/* Desired outputs:(?)

    Koningsdag 2017: Waar komt het vandaan?
    En wat u moet weten over deze dag

    King's Day 2017: You love it!
    You won't believe how old it is

    Queen of hearts: Foul-tempered.
    Find out what Alice did

    Wise owl: What goes up,
    must come down

    Shakespeare: Some are born great,
    some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them
*/

function report($res) {
    if (count($res)!==2) {throw new Exception("Unexpected result");}
    echo $res[0]."\n".$res[1]."\n\n";
}

function splitByPreg($title,$chars='.,?!') {
    //Split by $chars, capture the split marker so we can append it back to the first match
    // - If we see more than one $char we assume all further examples should be in part 2
    $parts=preg_split('/(['.preg_quote($chars,'/').'])\s*/', $title,2,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $n=count($parts);
    switch ($n) {
        case 3:
            //Expected
            return [$parts[0].$parts[1],$parts[2]];
        case 2:
            //Not sure how this could happen
            return $parts;
        case 1:
            //No delim found
            return [$parts[0],""];
    }
    return ["",""];
}

function splitByChar($title,$chars='.,?!') {
    //This returns the second line as a string starting with the break character
    $lineTwo=strpbrk($title,$chars);
    if ($lineTwo===false) return [$title,""];
    $n=strlen($title);
    $break=$n-strlen($lineTwo)+1;//+1 to move the break character to line1
    return [substr($title,0,$break),trim(substr($title,$break))];
}

foreach ($ts as $t) {
    //Pick one:
    $res=splitByPreg($t);
    //$res=splitByChar($t);
    report($res);
}
```

As you can see you can specify the delimiters to either method (if you wish to use more than/alternatives to the original four).  I've tested with a few, including `/` (which is only sometimes a control character in regex.